# Phase and Gain alignment

Tags: fft

I have simultaneously recorded data coming from three pre-amplifiers with same input applied to these pre-amps. After post analysis, i found that there are phase and gain differences among these outputs ( which should be zero in ideal case). I set one preamplifer output as reference and measure the phase and gain difference values of other two preamps with respect to this reference using "fft technique" for a typical frequency value.

Now question is how can i use these phase/gain difference values to align all three signals in software?

Note: Idea is to save these phase/gain coefficients permanently and multiply them with each corresponding preamplifier's outputs (excluding reference ) sample by sample for each acquisition so that inherent phase/gain difference b/w preamplifiers can be adjusted without modifying the electronics.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of recording are we talking about? For complex baseband signals, a phase and gain correction is just a simple multiplication with a complex constant...

Comment: Generally, what you describe sounds like you might need a full equalizer, since it's possible that your amplifiers don't work identically on all frequencies (in fact, that's likely), but your question is sadly a bit short on any details regarding what you're actually working on and what you're working with!

Comment: i am recording voltage signals in real form, however after digitization, complex demodulation (basebanding) has been performed in software. Actually these preamplifiers are connected with a linear array of sensors for direction finding and for correct direction finding, there should be no inherent phase and gain differences among preamps

Comment: What i want to do is to compensate any inherent phase and gain difference at preamps output w.r.t reference preamp in software (after digitization and base banding) without modifying electronics for a single frequency of interest. Do i have to compensate phase in frequency domain (i have to do FFT and IFFT for each acquired data block real time) or there is a way to do it in time domain?

Comment: How to define a complex constant if i have X phase difference and Y gain difference?